# How to create template in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I'm a new student in CakePHP 3 please resolve my problem. 
This is my controller file:

**DirectUseController.php**

```
<?php
class DirectUseController extends AppController {
    function index() {
        $this->layout = 'directuse';
    }
}
?>
```

This is my layout file:

**directuse.ctp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            <?= $this->fetch('title') ?>
        </title>
        </head>
    <body>
    <a href="#"> Bootstrap </a> | <a href="#"> Foundation </a> | <a href="#"> Materilize </a> 
    <br><br>
    Copyright
    <br><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my index file in folder of direct use
**index.ctp**

```
<section id="mainBody">
      hello 
</section>
```

and my folder structure is:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of cake you are using? Beqause when you used the latest version >3.4 `$this->layout = 'directuse'` will give a error. In that case you must use `$this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('directuse');`.

Answer (score 2):

Your layout should presumably include this somewhere:

```
echo $this->fetch('content');
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, you're going to have to be more specific about what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

- CakePHP prioritizes [convention](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html) over configuration, so try to change your Controller name to Direct**u**se**s**Controller, change also your layout folder's name (to DirectUses) and maybe your Model too (cake bake can easily help you), I don't know your [table name in the database] but it should be plural and in lowercase (directuses) (if you don't use database that's another story)
- For your template Greg Schmidt is [right](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your layout file you have to use this:

```
<?= $this->Flash->render(); ?>
<?= $this->fetch('content'); ?>
```

I prefer to add the `<html>` and `<body>` tags inside the `default.ctp` or `directuse.ctp` layout. On this way you do not have to rebuild your html every time. This will make your code a lot cleaner.